# When I break a block it reappears and when I place one it disappears?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am in survival and I even tried creative but when I break any block (in this case a stone block with a diamond pickaxe) it just reappears. I'm using version 1.7.9 and earlier today (18th of June) I was able to most normally break blocks. I've been playing this world for a while and it still won't work.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you online or single player? Sounds like lag to me.

Comment: If you are in multiplayer, try making yourself op or move a few blocks away from spawn.